# Working with EditText as with the TextView - onClickListener

Tags: android, android-edittext, onclicklistener

I have EditTexts intstead of TextViews so I can select some text to share.

```
  android:textIsSelectable="true"
  android:editable="false"
  android:inputType="none"
```

But I have problem setting onClickListener on it. It barely works, you may tap it 10 times before Log show me result.I can do this :

```
 android:focusable="false"
```

and onClickListener works fine with this, but I can't select any text to share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the text to be selectable, simply use a `TextView`. They have the `textIsSelectable` attribute too and give a nicer UX (because the user thinks he can edit text in `EditText`s, but he can't).

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me In this i am able to select text and can show a toast when it is clicked
Just long press your edittext box and you select as much text as it contains

layout.xml

```
<EditText
  android:id="@+id/justforFun"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Just for Fun"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:editable="false"
    android:textIsSelectable="true" >
</EditText>
```

Activity code

```
EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.justforFun);
    text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

Comment: why u want to do this use simple text view and things will be simpler for you , just asking out of curiosity :)

Comment: I didn't know it's possible))) always used EditText for that purpose

Answer (score 0):

```
  yourEditTextHere.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
     public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {                                                       
        // your code here....
        //open keyboard all the time
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);                
        return false;
     }
   });
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `TouchListner` instead of `clickListner`.

Reference: http://www.edureka.in/blog/android-tutorials-event-listeners